# whether circles intersect or not

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, loops

I have a matrix, which looks like this:

```
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 2 1.5
```

which means (X, Y, R) of the circle (first it's circle's center, second it's radius)

this matrix is dynamically created, so it can have all sizes you wish, just enter it's one.

I need to find out whether these circles intersect or not, I'm doing it like this:

```
 for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) {
    dis_x = fabs(*(matrix + (i+1) * 3 + 0) - *(matrix + i * 3 + 0));
    dis_y = fabs(*(matrix + (i+1) * 3 + 1) - *(matrix + i * 3 + 1));
    hypotenuse = sqrt( pow(dis_x,2) + pow(dis_y,2) );

    radius_i = *(matrix + i * 3 + 2);
    radius_i_plus_1 = *(matrix + (i+1) * 3 + 2);

    sum_of_radius = radius_i_plus_1 + radius_i;

    if( sum_of_radius >= hypotenuse && hypotenuse != 0) {
        *(array_of_numbers_of_circles + i * 2 + 0) = i + 1;
        *(array_of_numbers_of_circles + i * 2 + 1) = i + 2;
    }

}
```

if I take the example above, I will see:
2 3

but I need:

```
1 3
2 3
```

in other words I need to compare ALL elements even first with last (if the size is 3) and all elements : the second with the forth (if the size is 4+)

thank you in advance!

Comment: Well so you need a nested loop. Just intersect every pair of circles. Or is that too slow?

Comment: You want something like `for( int i = 0; i < n; i++ ) { for( int j = i + 1; j < n; j++ ) { test if circle i and circle j intersect } }`

Comment: You should also check that the radii differ less than the distance between centers. If the difference is bigger than the distance, circles are nested.

Comment: @Salixalba, yes it is, but I need to count the dis_x,dis_y and so on...how can I do that? what will be in the *(matrix + ?*3 + 0) - *(matrix + ?*3 + 0) ? thx!

Comment: @KonstantinRasskazov That's a strange way to do it. Usually you would have `matrix` defined as a 2-dimensional array: `int matrix[n][3]`. And then it is just `dis_x = fabs(matrix[i][0] - matrix[j][0])` etc.

Comment: `dis_x = *(matrix + i * 3 + 0) - *(matrix + j * 3 + 0);` will do. (Don't need fabs as squared in the next line).

Comment: Why not treat the circles as squares in the first instance to throw out those that do not need to be tested?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
count = 0;
for( int i = 0; i < n-1; i++ ) {
  for( int j= i + 1;  j < n ; j++) {
    dis_x = *(matrix + j * 3 + 0) - *(matrix + i * 3 + 0); // no need for fabs
    dis_y = *(matrix + j * 3 + 1) - *(matrix + i * 3 + 1);

    // use squared form, use multiplication rather than pow
    hypSquared = dis_x * dis_x + dis_y * dis_y; 

    radius_i = *(matrix + i * 3 + 2);
    radius_j = *(matrix + j * 3 + 2);

    sum_of_radius = radius_i + radius_j;
    diff_of_radius = radius_i - radius_j;
    // compare square of radius to the square of hyp. Eliminates call to sqrt()
    if( sum_of_radius * sum_of_radius >= hypSquared
     && diff_of_radius * diff_of_radius < hypSquared  ) {
        *(array_of_numbers_of_circles + count * 2 + 0) = i + 1;
        *(array_of_numbers_of_circles + count * 2 + 1) = j + 2;
        ++count;
    }

}
```

Comment: You have forgotten the case in which one circle is mostly inside the other.  See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367512/algorithm-to-detect-if-a-circles-intersect-with-any-other-circle-in-the-same-pla

Comment: You need to compare the distance of centres is betweens `abs(r1 - r2)` and `r1 + r2`.

Comment: Thanks for accepting my answer. I must say the other answers are better, a class or struct will make further work better.

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
struct circle
{
    double x, y, r;
    bool empty() { return x==0.0 && y==0.0 && r==0.0; }
};

circle matrix[] = {
    {0, 0, 1},
    {0, 0, 2},
    {0, 2, 1.5},
    {0,0,0}  // end marker
};

bool intersect(circle &c1, circle &c2)
{
    double dx = c2.x - c1.x;
    double dy = c2.y - c1.y;
    double dist = sqrt(dx*dx + dy*dy);
    double sumRad = c2.r + c1.r;
    bool yes = false;
    if (sumRad >= dist)
    {
        double minR = c1.r;
        double maxR = c2.r;
        if (minR > maxR) std::swap(minR, maxR);
        if (dist + minR >= maxR || (dist == 0.0 && minR == maxR))
            yes = true;
    }
    return yes;
}

void test()
{
    std::vector<std::pair<int, int>> result;
    for (int i=0; !matrix[i].empty(); i++)
        for (int j=i+1; !matrix[j].empty(); j++)
            if (intersect(matrix[i], matrix[j]))
                result.push_back(std::pair<int, int>(i+1,j+1));

    for (int i =0; i < result.size(); i++)
        printf("%d %d\n", result[i].first, result[i].second);
}
```

Output of executing test() is:

```
1 3
2 3
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd be inclined to approach it like this. The first thing is to create a Circle class

```
class Circle 
{
public:
    friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const Circle &c) 
        { return out << '(' << c.x << ", " << c.y << ", " << c.r << ')'; };
    friend std::istream &operator>>(std::istream &in, Circle &c) 
        { return in >> c.x >> c.y >> c.r; };
    bool intersects(const Circle &c2) const;
private:
    float x, y, r;
};

bool Circle::intersects(const Circle &c2) const
{
    float dist_squared = (x-c2.x)*(x-c2.x)+(y-c2.y)*(y-c2.y);
    if ((r-c2.r)*(r-c2.r) > dist_squared)
        return false;
    return (r+c2.r)*(r+c2.r) >= dist_squared;
}
```

Note that this class includes its own stream inserter and extractor and a member function `intersects` which tells whether any two `Circle` class instances intersect. Obviously, all error checking is omitted here, but it gives the essence of the technique.

I show how to use it in a complete program below.  This program uses C++ 2011 features which make it quite compact, but they're not essential to using the `Circle` class.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

//  the above Circle code would go here...

int main()
{
    std::ifstream in("circles.txt");
    std::vector<Circle> circles;

    std::copy(std::istream_iterator<Circle>(in), 
        std::istream_iterator<Circle>(), 
        std::back_inserter(circles));

    for (auto i : circles)
        for (auto j : circles)
            if (i.intersects(j))
                std::cout << i << " intersects " << j << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

If the file `circles.txt` is a text file containing exactly the input given:

```
0 0 1
0 0 2
0 2 1.5
```

the output is:

```
(0, 0, 1) intersects (0, 0, 1)
(0, 0, 1) intersects (0, 2, 1.5)
(0, 0, 2) intersects (0, 0, 2)
(0, 0, 2) intersects (0, 2, 1.5)
(0, 2, 1.5) intersects (0, 0, 1)
(0, 2, 1.5) intersects (0, 0, 2)
(0, 2, 1.5) intersects (0, 2, 1.5)
```

Note that this version reports that each circle intersects with itself.  Technically true, but probably not very useful!  The driver code could, of course, be rewritten without C++11 features and to give some alternate form of output.  One way to do that would be to substitute this code for the nested `for` loops in the code above:

```
for (int i = 0; i < circles.size(); ++i)
    for (int j = i+1; j < circles.size(); ++j)
        if (circles[i].intersects(circles[j]))
            std::cout << i+1 << " " << j+1 << std::endl;
```

Doing so yields the following output:

```
1 3
2 3
```