# 2D simple ball collision vector

Tags: javascript, canvas, collision-detection

Trying to get two balls to collide and bounce back at appropriate angles.
When the balls collide however they get stuck together and I have no idea what I'm doing wrong here.

I'm calling this `checkCollision()` function within my animate function
Obviously `cx` is ball1 `xpos`, `cx2` is ball2 `xpos`. Same for `cy`.

```
function checkCollision () {
    var dx = cx2 - cx;  // distance between x
    var dy = cy2 - cy;  // distance between y
    var distance = Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy); 

    if (distance < (radius1 + radius2)) {
        // Collision detected. Find the normal.
        var normalX = dx / distance;
        var normalY = dy / distance;

        //find the middle point of the distance
        var midpointX = (cx + cx2)/2;
        var midpointY = (cy + cy2)/2;

        //bounce back
        cx = midpointX - radius1*normalX;
        cy = midpointY - radius1*normalY;
        cx2 = midpointX - radius2*normalX;
        cy2 = midpointY - radius2*normalY;

        var dVector = (vx - vx2) * normalX;
        dVector += (vy - vy2) * normalY;

        var dvx = dVector * normalX;
        var dvy = dVector * normalY;

        vx -= dvx;
        vy -= dvy;
        vx2 += dvx;
        vy2 += dvy;
    }
    ...
```

I've never done much/any vector work. Is there any easier way to do this?
How would I write this with angles instead?

Comment: Why do you subtract the velocity of the normal vector from the current velocity? Shouldn't you just set the velocity equal to the velocity of the normal vector? Like this `vx = dvx; vy = dvy;`

Comment: It could be that your balls are stuck in an infinite state of collision (wow, that sounded strange).

Comment: well to be honest @mpadittech I'm not 100% my friend helped me write this it's not my forte at all, i tried your way and the balls got stuck on collision as well though.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use some basic maths to detect the intersection between two circles.

A similar problem is described here:

[algorithm to detect if a Circles intersect with any other circle in the same plane](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367512/algorithm-to-detect-if-a-circles-intersect-with-any-other-circle-in-the-same-pla)

There is a C# sample that could be easily adapted to Javascript.