# how to prevent overlapping of 2 components

Tags: javascript, p5.js

how to prevent overlapping of 2 components, please help me to make them follow Mouse but not overlap. i am not expert in coding, please explain in simple language.

```js
function component(x,y,r) {
       var randomcolor = ["violet","indigo","blue","green","yellow","orange","red"];
    this.pos=createVector(x,y);
    this.r=r;
    this.color=randomcolor[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomcolor.length)];
    this.show=function() {
     fill(this.color);
      stroke(241,241,241);
     ellipse(this.pos.x,this.pos.y,this.r*2,this.r*2);
    }
    this.crash = function(other) {
      var d = p5.Vector.dist(this.pos,other.pos);
    if (d<this.r+other.r) {
      this.r+=other.r/20;
      return true;}

}
    
    this.move=function(){
      this.pos.x=lerp(this.pos.x,mouseX,0.1);
      this.pos.y=lerp(this.pos.y,mouseY,0.1);
this.pos.x = constrain(this.pos.x,this.r,width-this.r)
this.pos.y = constrain(this.pos.y,this.r,height-this.r)

}    
}
```

Comment: You should have a list of Vector then when move you iterate throw all and check for collision. read here someone with the same problem https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30363537/2d-simple-ball-collision-vector

Comment: @Alen.Toma i can detect collision, but how to stop the ball at  collision?

Comment: I edited your code so that it can run. I made some assumptions about what your draw function should be but tried to stay consistent with your original code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make multiple objects move without running into each other you will need to

- keep track of the current location of all objects
- be able to identify each object so that the collision method does not detect a collision of an object with itself
- check to make sure there will not be a collision before attempting to move an object

For your example code this is one possibility for making multiple components move towards the mouse without running into each other. I rewrote your crash function and added some global variables. This is not elegant but I think it answers your question in a way that you can understand how this kind of problem can be approached.

```js
var ids = 0;
var allComponents = [];
function setup(){
  createCanvas(600,600);
  new component(10,10,10);
  new component(590,10,10);
}

function draw(){
   background(255);
   for (let i = 0; i < allComponents.length; i++){
     allComponents[i].show();
     allComponents[i].move();
   }
}
function component(x,y,r) {
    var randomcolor = ["violet","indigo","blue","green","yellow","orange","red"];
    this.pos=createVector(x,y);
    this.r=r;
    this.id = ids++;
    allComponents[allComponents.length] = this;         
    this.color=randomcolor[Math.floor(Math.random()*randomcolor.length)];
    this.show=function() {
      fill(this.color);
      stroke(241,241,241);
      ellipse(this.pos.x,this.pos.y,this.r*2,this.r*2);
    }
    this.crash = function(other) {
      var d = p5.Vector.dist(this.pos,other.pos);
      if (d< this.r + other.r) {
        return true;
      }
      return false;
    }
    
    this.move=function(){
      let originalX = this.pos.x;
      let originalY = this.pos.y;
      this.pos.x=lerp(this.pos.x,mouseX,0.1);
      this.pos.y=lerp(this.pos.y,mouseY,0.1);
      this.pos.x = constrain(this.pos.x,this.r,width-this.r);
      this.pos.y = constrain(this.pos.y,this.r,height-this.r);
      for (let i = 0; i < allComponents.length; i++){
        let other = allComponents[i];
        if (this.id !== other.id && this.crash(other)){
          this.pos.x = originalX;
          this.pos.y = originalY;
          break;
        }
      }  
    }    
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/p5.js/0.7.3/p5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it seems like if a circle moves then another circle get attracted to that circle, is it possible to make all circle getting attracted to mouse but not overlap?

Comment: You can make the move function more sophisticated by adding logic to move around the object that it is colliding with when a collision happens. The code in the answer simply prevents collisions. You could put a loop in move that tries some random directions when a collisions happens.