# Python Pygame randomly draw non overlapping circles

Tags: python, random, pygame

Im very new to python and seem to be missing something.
I want to randomly draw circles on a pygame display but only if the circles don't overlap each other.
I believe I must find the distance between all circle centers and only draw it if the distance is bigger than `circle radius * 2`.

I've tried many different things but all without success, I always get the same result - circles drawn overlapping.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import pygame, random, math

red = (255, 0, 0)
width = 800
height = 600
circle_num = 10
tick = 2
speed = 5

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

class circle():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0,width)
        self.y = random.randint(0,height)
        self.r = 100

    def new(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, (self.x,self.y), self.r, tick)

c = []
for i in range(circle_num):
    c.append('c'+str(i))
    c[i] = circle()
    for j in range(len(c)):
        dist = int(math.hypot(c[i].x - c[j].x, c[i].y - c[j].y))
        if dist > int(c[i].r*2 + c[j].r*2):
            c[j].new()
            pygame.display.update()

        else:
            continue

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You did not check against all other circles. I added a variable `shouldprint` which gets set to false if any other circle is too close.

```
import pygame, random, math

red = (255, 0, 0)
width = 800
height = 600
circle_num = 20
tick = 2
speed = 5

pygame.init()
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height))

class circle():
    def __init__(self):
        self.x = random.randint(0,width)
        self.y = random.randint(0,height)
        self.r = 100

    def new(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, red, (self.x,self.y), self.r, tick)

c = []
for i in range(circle_num):
    c.append('c'+str(i))
    c[i] = circle()
    shouldprint = True
    for j in range(len(c)):
        if i != j:
            dist = int(math.hypot(c[i].x - c[j].x, c[i].y - c[j].y))
            if dist < int(c[i].r*2):
                shouldprint = False
    if shouldprint:
        c[i].new()
        pygame.display.update()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            quit()
```

Comment: Thanks Yeah I see now what I missed.

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop has been changed to a `while` loop. It will keep trying to generate circles until the target number is reached. A circle is first generated. Then, it checks if it intersects with any existing circle using the formula from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8367547/5717792) answer.

It iterates through every existing circle (store in the list `circles`) and performs the check using the formula. `any()` returns `True` if the formula evaluates to `True` for any iteration. If it's `True`, it means it found an intersection. Thus, it continues to the next iteration to try again with a new circle.

```
circles = []
while len(circles) < circle_num:
    new = circle()

    if any(pow(c.r - new.r, 2) <=
           pow(c.x - new.x, 2) + pow(c.y - new.y, 2) <=
           pow(c.r + new.r, 2)
       for c in circles):
        continue

    circles.append(new)
    new.new()
    pygame.display.update()
```

Comment: Thanks.  It works but its a completely different way than mine.  Will studie it and learn from it