# Intersection detection between two circles not working

Tags: javascript, math, geometry, collision, intersection

I'm trying to use [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8367547/962155) to detect whether or not there is an intersection between two circles. The answer says: `The above solution should work even for the "one circle inside the other" case.`

However, when I try with the following input:

```
x0: 296
y0: 728
r0: 14

x1: 299
y1: 731
r1: 7
```

Which looks like this visually:

[image]

Then it doesn't seem to work. That is, the following equation fails:

`(R0 - R1)^2 <= (x0 - x1)^2 + (y0 - y1)^2 <= (R0 + R1)^2`

`49 <= 18 <= 441`

That is, the function would return false (they do not intersect), when clearly they are intersecting.

Am I doing something wrong, or is the formula not correct?

Comment: So all I need to do is remove the left-side of the equation, and then it will work? That is, to use `(x0 - x1)^2 + (y0 - y1)^2 <= (R0 + R1)^2` instead?

Comment: Oh, they deleted their comment.

Comment: ^^ Yes.  Only check (r0 + r1), the (r0 - r1) part is what allows for nested circles that don't intersect - so remove it.

Answer (score 0):

The circles are nested, but not intersecting

Comment: Is it possible to modify the equation to make it work such that it also returns true when they're nested?

Answer (score 0):

Let's consider two **exterior** circles, which means they have nothing in common, not even a tangent point.

Such circles verify that the distance between their centers is greater than the sum of their radious.

Thus (pseudocode):

```
//we don't need to calculate square roots. Squaring is enough and faster.
centerDist2 = (c1x - c2x)^2 + (c1y-c2y)^2
radiousSum2 = (R1 + R2)^2
//condition test
if centerDist2 > radiousSum2
  return false //no intersection
else
  return true
```

Notice the `>` in the test. This excludes tangents. If you want them to get included as "intersection" then substitute with `>=`

Also, due to floating numbers issues you better use some threshold:

```
littleValue = 0.0001
if centerDist2 > (radiousSum2 - littleValue)
...
```