# Javascript: Find out if two circles overlap

Tags: javascript, geometry

Really simple question for someone who doesn't know geometry or formulae. I need to know if two circles intersect. That's it.

I have two circles: circle1 and circle2. These two circles are the same size with the same radius. They'll never be different. I need a formula to show me if these circles overlap. I don't care where. I don't care how much. I don't care about any details but true or false. Do the circles overlap or not? I just need something I can est for in Javascript.

The formula here doesn't work for me. [How do I detect intersections between a circle and any other circle in the same plane?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8367512/how-do-i-detect-intersections-between-a-circle-and-any-other-circle-in-the-same) Nor does anything on Google.

I've been racking my brain and Google searching for three hours, and no formula that I find works.

Can anybody please help??

Comment: What info do you have? Seems that they overlap if the centers are within one radius of each other in distance. The line connecting the centers are the hypotenuse of a triangle.

Comment: I don't know how to calculate if the centers are within one radius of each other. I know how to calculate if the X points are within one radius or the Y points, but I don't know a formula that calculates if both are simultaneously within one radius...if that makes sense. When you say hypotenuse of a triangle, do you mean:

distance = square root ( (X point of circle1 - X point of circle2)^2 + (Y point of circle1 - Y point of circle2)^2 )

Comment: yes exactly! I was incorrect before though, that distance just needs to be twice the radius or less (you can draw on paper to see why)

Comment: so it seems the condition you're looking for is `square root ( (X point of circle1 - X point of circle2)^2 + (Y point of circle1 - Y point of circle2)^2 ) <= 2 * radius`

Comment: not radius *2 but radius of circle one+ radius of circle two

Comment: plus it is best to use absolute values everywhere otherwise you have to keep track of which one is higher Math.abs(X point of circle1 - X point of circle2)^2 + Math.abs(Y point of circle1 - Y point of circle2)^2 )

Comment: Thanks @Nick! That breakdown worked. I think part of my problem was that, in Javascript, I guess ^ isn't exponential? I got weird results. I did ** instead, and that seemed to be to the power of 2. I guess the carat isn't the exponential operator in JS?

Comment: Thanks, @SolomonPByer. I added the absolute values. The radii are always the same, so radius 1 + radius 2 would be the same as radius1*2. But in a case where the two circles are different, adding them would work instead.

Answer (score 2):

Use the builtin [Math.hypot](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/hypot) function to calculate the distance between the centers of the two circles. If this is less than or equal the sum of the radii then the circles overlap.

```js
function circleIntersect(x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1) {
    return Math.hypot(x0 - x1, y0 - y1) <= r0 + r1;
}

console.log(circleIntersect(0, 0, 2, 3, 0, 2));

console.log(circleIntersect(0, 0, 2, 5, 0, 2));
```

Comment: Thanks, RaffleBuffle! I didn't even know Math.hypot existed. I'm going to try to incorporate that into my code when I get a moment after work, since it's surely faster and more robust than what I've currently got. Stay tuned!

Answer (score 1):

this is a function that will return if they are overlapping

```
function overLapping(CircleOneX,CircleOneY,CircleOneRadius,CircleTwoX,CircleTwoY,CircleTwoRadius){
 return Math.sqrt(Math.abs(CircleOneX-CircleTwoX)+ Math.abs(CircleOneY-CircleTwoY))<(CircleOneRadius+CircleTwoRadius)
}
```

Comment: That formula is wrong.  Math.sqrt((CircleOneX-CircleTwoX) ** 2 + (CircleOneY-CircleTwoY) ** 2 ) < CircleOneRadius+CircleTwoRadius