# Intersection points between two circles of different radius with latitude and longitude geospatial in javascript

Tags: javascript, geometry, geospatial

I've got a problem trying to figure out the intersection between two circles of different radius .. I took one of theses answers here : [Google Maps Two Circles Intersection Points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469582/google-maps-two-circles-intersection-points)
and tryed to make an interactive example here, but I later found out the leaflet map isn't working in this way ..

My Idea was to balance the equilibrium "middle" point between two circles with a variable pf " power factor " but as soon as i change position or radius, the compensation factor isn't the same anymore, so I feel a little lost between line 59 to 89 .. the solution must be simple but I can't put my finger on it ..

Any clue, help, comment, notice, enlightment would be greatly appreciated :)

```js
var lat1 = 45.916, lng1 = 6.116, r1 = 30 // Ncy
    , lat2 = 46.2, lng2 = 6.145, r2 = 2, pf=0.5,
    prop,shift,shift2x,shift2y,shift2z,shift,realMiddle,middle2,middle,mid
    ,produitCroise,angle,d1,s1,t1,d2,s2,t2,SS1,SS2,Sa1,Sa2,SS3,S1,S2,S3,S1_latlng,S2_latlng,s1,s2,t1,t2
    ,e,m1,P1,P2,dist,R=6371,R2=R*R, DEG2RAD = Math.PI/180, blue = new L.Icon({shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png', iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41], popupAnchor: [1, -34], shadowSize: [41, 41],iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-blue.png'}), red = new L.Icon({ shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png', iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41], popupAnchor: [1, -34], shadowSize: [41, 41],iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-red.png'}),green = new L.Icon({ shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png', iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41], popupAnchor: [1, -34], shadowSize: [41, 41],iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-green.png'}),yellow = new L.Icon({ shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png', iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41], popupAnchor: [1, -34], shadowSize: [41, 41],iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-yellow.png'}),orange = new L.Icon({ shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png', iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41], popupAnchor: [1, -34], shadowSize: [41, 41],iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-orange.png'}),
zoom = 9,osm = new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {minZoom: 2, maxZoom: 19, attribution: ''}),

si=setInterval(function(){if(typeof L=='undefined')return;clearInterval(si);si=null;refreshMap();},50);

function refreshMap() {

    if ((r1 / 2 + r2 / 2) > dist) {
        document.getElementById('e').innerHTML = 'one circle is within another';
    } else if ((r1 + r2) < dist) {
        document.getElementById('e').innerHTML = 'do not intersect : too far away';
    } else {
        dist = distance(lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2);
        P1 = LatLng2Cartesian(lat1, lng1);
        P2 = LatLng2Cartesian(lat2, lng2);

        prop = pf + (r1 / (r1 + r2));// would probably compensate the radiuses difference for calculating the middle balance point
        shift = {x: P2.x - P1.x, y: P2.y - P1.y, z: P2.z - P1.z};
        shift2x = P2.x - P1.x;shift2y = P2.y - P1.y;shift2z = P2.z - P1.z;
        realMiddle = {x: P1.x + P2.x, y: P1.y + P2.y, z: P1.z + P2.z};
        //, middle = {x: (P1.x + P2.x*prop), y: (P1.y + P2.y*prop), z: (P1.z + P2.z*prop)}, middle2=middle, mid = Cartesian2LatLng(middle)
        middle = {x: (P1.x + P2.x) + shift2x * prop, y: (P1.y + P2.y) + shift2y * prop, z: (P1.z + P2.z) + shift2z * prop};
        middle2 = middle;
        mid = Cartesian2LatLng(middle);

        angle = Math.acos(P1.x * P2.x + P1.y * P2.y + P1.z * P2.z); // the angle P1OP2
        produitCroise = crossProd(P1, P2); // normal vector to plane OP1P2 = vector along S1S2

        d1 = r1 * r1 / (2 * R); s1 = (R - d1) / Math.cos(angle / 2); t1 = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(R2 - s1 * s1));
        d2 = r2 * r2 / (2 * R); s2 = (R - d2) / Math.cos(angle / 2); t2 = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(R2 - s2 * s2));
/*
This is the messy part of copied code where I don't really understand what going on
if the value rs for the distance along the surface is known, it has to be converted:
var r = 2*R*Math.sin(rs/(2*R*Math.PI));
Now let S1 and S2 be the intersections points and S their mid-point. With s = |OS| and t = |SS1| = |SS2| (where O = (0,0,0) is the earth's center) we get from simple derivations:
*/
        SS1 = vecScale(t1 / vecLen(produitCroise), produitCroise);SS2 = vecScale(t2 / vecLen(produitCroise), produitCroise);
        Sa1 = vecScale(s1 / vecLen(middle), middle);Sa2 = vecScale(s2 / vecLen(middle2), middle2);

        SS3 = {x: SS1.x - SS2.x, y: SS1.y - SS2.y, z: SS1.z - SS2.z};

        S1 = {x: Sa1.x + SS1.x, y: Sa1.y + SS1.y, z: Sa1.z + SS1.z}; // S + SS1 , the right one
        S2 = {x: Sa1.x - SS1.x, y: Sa1.y - SS1.y, z: Sa1.z - SS1.z}; // S - SS1 , the right one

        S1 = {x: Sa2.x + SS2.x, y: Sa2.y + SS2.y, z: Sa2.z + SS2.z}, S2 = {x: Sa2.x - SS2.x, y: Sa2.y - SS2.y, z: Sa2.z - SS2.z};

        S3 = {x: Sa2.x - SS2.x, y: Sa2.y - SS2.y, z: Sa2.z - SS2.z};

        S1_latlng = Cartesian2LatLng(S1);
        S2_latlng = Cartesian2LatLng(S2);

        x = {mid, dist, P1, P2, SS1, t2, SS2, vl: vecLen(produitCroise)};
        console.log(x);
        document.getElementById('e').innerHTML = '';//"m:" + r(mid.lat, 3) + ',' + r(mid.lng, 3) + "\n" + r(S1_latlng.lat, 3) + ',' + r(S1_latlng.lng, 3) + "\n" + r(S2_latlng.lat, 3) + ',' + r(S2_latlng.lng, 3) + "\n\n\n" + JSON.stringify(S1_latlng) + "\n" + JSON.stringify(S2_latlng) + "\n\n" + JSON.stringify(x);

        if(m1)m1.remove();
        m1 = L.map('m1').setView([r3(mid.lat), r3(mid.lng)], zoom).addLayer(osm);

        L.marker([lat2, lng2], {icon: green}).addTo(m1);
        L.circle([lat2, lng2], {color: 'red', fillColor: '#f03', fillOpacity: 0.1, radius: r2 * 1000}).addTo(m1);
        L.marker([lat1, lng1], {icon: green}).addTo(m1);
        L.circle([lat1, lng1], {color: 'red', fillColor: '#f03', fillOpacity: 0.1, radius: r1 * 1000}).addTo(m1);
        L.marker([r3(mid.lat), r3(mid.lng)], {icon: red}).addTo(m1);
        L.marker([r3(S1_latlng.lat), r3(S1_latlng.lng)]).addTo(m1);
        L.marker([r3(S2_latlng.lat), r3(S2_latlng.lng)]).addTo(m1);
    }
}






function r3(x) {return r(x,3);}
function r(x,exp) {
    var round=Math.pow(10,exp),r=x*round;
    return Math.round(r)/round;
}

function LatLng2Cartesian(lat_deg,lng_deg)
{
    var lat_rad = lat_deg*DEG2RAD,lng_rad = lng_deg*DEG2RAD,cos_lat = Math.cos(lat_rad);
    return {x: Math.cos(lng_rad)*cos_lat, y: Math.sin(lng_rad)*cos_lat, z: Math.sin(lat_rad)};
}

function Cartesian2LatLng(P)
{
    var P_xy = {x: P.x, y:P.y, z:0}
    return {lng: Math.atan2(P.y,P.x)/DEG2RAD, lat: Math.atan2(P.z,vecLen(P_xy))/DEG2RAD};
}

function vecLen(v) {
    return Math.sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y + v.z * v.z);
}

function vecScale(scale, v) {
    return {x: scale * v.x, y: scale * v.y, z: scale * v.z};
}


function crossProd(v1, v2) {
    return {
        x: v1.y * v2.z - v1.z * v2.y,
        y: v1.z * v2.x - v1.x * v2.z,
        z: v1.x * v2.y - v1.y * v2.x
    };
}
//haversine method
function distance(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2) {
    return getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2)
}
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2) {
    var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
    var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1);
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    var d = R * c; // Distance in km
    return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {return deg * DEG2RAD;}

function onsubmite(f){
    try {
        lat1=parseFloat(f.lat1.value);
        lat2=parseFloat(f.lat2.value);
        lng1=parseFloat(f.lon1.value);
        lng2=parseFloat(f.lon2.value);
        r1=parseFloat(f.rad1.value);
        r2=parseFloat(f.rad2.value);
        pf=parseFloat(f.pf.value);
        refreshMap();
    }catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

```css
html{font-size:10px;}body{margin:auto;}#e{width:100vw;height:15%;}
.map{height:75%;border:1px dashed #F00;}
*{font-size:1rem;} input {width:5rem;} .w100{width:100%}
```

```html
<html><head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
</head><body>

<form onSubmit="return onsubmite(this);">Lat1 : <input name="lat1" value="45.916">Lon1 : <input name="lon1" value="6.116">Rad1 : <input name="rad1" value="30"> - Lat2 : <input name="lat2" value="46.2">Lon2 : <input name="lon2" value="6.145">Rad2 : <input name="rad2" value="12"> | Pf : <input name="pf" value="0">
<br><input type="submit" value="Update coordinates" class="w100"></form>
<textarea id="e"></textarea>
<div class="map" id="m1"></div>
</body></html>
```

Here's the full working example :

```
<html><head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.css"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.9.4/dist/leaflet.js"></script>
<style>
    html{font-size:10px;}body{margin:auto;}#e{width:100vw;height:15%;}.map{height:75%}*{font-size:1rem;} input {width:5rem;} .w50{width:50%}
</style></head><body>

<form onSubmit="return onsubmite(this);">Lat1 : <input name="lat1" value="45.916">Lon1 : <input name="lon1" value="6.116">Rad1 : <input name="rad1" value="30"> - Lat2 : <input name="lat2" value="46.2">Lon2 : <input name="lon2" value="6.145">Rad2 : <input name="rad2" value="12"> | Pf : <input name="pf" value="0">
<br><input type="submit" value="maj" class="w50"></form>
<textarea id="e"></textarea>
<div class="map" id="m1"></div>
</body></html><script>
/*
code inspired by
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68841444/javascript-find-out-if-two-circles-overlap
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22469582/google-maps-two-circles-intersection-points
*/
function onsubmite(f){
    try {
        lat1=parseFloat(f.lat1.value);
        lat2=parseFloat(f.lat2.value);
        lng1=parseFloat(f.lon1.value);
        lng2=parseFloat(f.lon2.value);
        r1=parseFloat(f.rad1.value);
        r2=parseFloat(f.rad2.value);
        pf=parseFloat(f.pf.value);
        refreshMap();
    }catch(e) {
        console.error(e);
    }
    return false;
}

var lat1 = 45.916, lng1 = 6.116, r1 = 30 // Ncy
    , lat2 = 46.2, lng2 = 6.145, r2 = 2, pf=0.5,
    prop,shift,shift2x,shift2y,shift2z,shift,realMiddle,middle2,middle,mid
    ,produitCroise,angle,d1,s1,t1,d2,s2,t2,SS1,SS2,Sa1,Sa2,SS3,S1,S2,S3,S1_latlng,S2_latlng,s1,s2,t1,t2
    ,markers=[],circles=[],e,m1,P1,P2,dist,R=6371,R2=R*R, DEG2RAD = Math.PI/180, blue = new L.Icon({shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png', iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41], popupAnchor: [1, -34], shadowSize: [41, 41],iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-blue.png'}), red = new L.Icon({ shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png', iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41], popupAnchor: [1, -34], shadowSize: [41, 41],iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-red.png'}),green = new L.Icon({ shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png', iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41], popupAnchor: [1, -34], shadowSize: [41, 41],iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-green.png'}),yellow = new L.Icon({ shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png', iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41], popupAnchor: [1, -34], shadowSize: [41, 41],iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-yellow.png'}),orange = new L.Icon({ shadowUrl: 'https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet/0.7.7/images/marker-shadow.png', iconSize: [25, 41], iconAnchor: [12, 41], popupAnchor: [1, -34], shadowSize: [41, 41],iconUrl: 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pointhi/leaflet-color-markers/master/img/marker-icon-2x-orange.png'}),
zoom = 9,osm = new L.TileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {minZoom: 2, maxZoom: 19, attribution: ''});

refreshMap();

function refreshMap() {

    if ((r1 / 2 + r2 / 2) > dist) {
        document.getElementById('e').innerHTML = 'one circle is within another';
    } else if ((r1 + r2) < dist) {
        document.getElementById('e').innerHTML = 'do not intersect : too far away';
    } else {
        dist = distance(lng1, lat1, lng2, lat2);
        P1 = LatLng2Cartesian(lat1, lng1);
        P2 = LatLng2Cartesian(lat2, lng2);

        prop = pf + (r1 / (r1 + r2));// would probably compensate the radiuses difference for calculating the middle balance point
        shift = {x: P2.x - P1.x, y: P2.y - P1.y, z: P2.z - P1.z};
        shift2x = P2.x - P1.x;shift2y = P2.y - P1.y;shift2z = P2.z - P1.z;
        realMiddle = {x: P1.x + P2.x, y: P1.y + P2.y, z: P1.z + P2.z};
        //, middle = {x: (P1.x + P2.x*prop), y: (P1.y + P2.y*prop), z: (P1.z + P2.z*prop)}, middle2=middle, mid = Cartesian2LatLng(middle)
        middle = {x: (P1.x + P2.x) + shift2x * prop, y: (P1.y + P2.y) + shift2y * prop, z: (P1.z + P2.z) + shift2z * prop};
        middle2 = middle;
        mid = Cartesian2LatLng(middle);

        angle = Math.acos(P1.x * P2.x + P1.y * P2.y + P1.z * P2.z); // the angle P1OP2
        produitCroise = crossProd(P1, P2); // normal vector to plane OP1P2 = vector along S1S2

        d1 = r1 * r1 / (2 * R); s1 = (R - d1) / Math.cos(angle / 2); t1 = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(R2 - s1 * s1));
        d2 = r2 * r2 / (2 * R); s2 = (R - d2) / Math.cos(angle / 2); t2 = Math.sqrt(Math.abs(R2 - s2 * s2));
/*
This is the messy part of copied code where I don't really understand what going on
if the value rs for the distance along the surface is known, it has to be converted:
var r = 2*R*Math.sin(rs/(2*R*Math.PI));
Now let S1 and S2 be the intersections points and S their mid-point. With s = |OS| and t = |SS1| = |SS2| (where O = (0,0,0) is the earth's center) we get from simple derivations:
*/
        SS1 = vecScale(t1 / vecLen(produitCroise), produitCroise);SS2 = vecScale(t2 / vecLen(produitCroise), produitCroise);
        Sa1 = vecScale(s1 / vecLen(middle), middle);Sa2 = vecScale(s2 / vecLen(middle2), middle2);

        SS3 = {x: SS1.x - SS2.x, y: SS1.y - SS2.y, z: SS1.z - SS2.z};

        S1 = {x: Sa1.x + SS1.x, y: Sa1.y + SS1.y, z: Sa1.z + SS1.z}; // S + SS1 , the right one
        S2 = {x: Sa1.x - SS1.x, y: Sa1.y - SS1.y, z: Sa1.z - SS1.z}; // S - SS1 , the right one

        S1 = {x: Sa2.x + SS2.x, y: Sa2.y + SS2.y, z: Sa2.z + SS2.z}, S2 = {x: Sa2.x - SS2.x, y: Sa2.y - SS2.y, z: Sa2.z - SS2.z};

        S3 = {x: Sa2.x - SS2.x, y: Sa2.y - SS2.y, z: Sa2.z - SS2.z};

        S1_latlng = Cartesian2LatLng(S1);
        S2_latlng = Cartesian2LatLng(S2);

        x = {dist, P1, P2, SS1, t2, SS2, mid, vl: vecLen(produitCroise)};
        console.error(x);
        document.getElementById('e').innerHTML = "m:" + r(mid.lat, 3) + ',' + r(mid.lng, 3) + "\n" + r(S1_latlng.lat, 3) + ',' + r(S1_latlng.lng, 3) + "\n" + r(S2_latlng.lat, 3) + ',' + r(S2_latlng.lng, 3) + "\n\n\n" + JSON.stringify(S1_latlng) + "\n" + JSON.stringify(S2_latlng) + "\n\n" + JSON.stringify(x);

        if(m1)m1.remove();
        m1 = L.map('m1').setView([r3(mid.lat), r3(mid.lng)], zoom).addLayer(osm);


        L.marker([lat2, lng2], {icon: green}).addTo(m1);
        L.circle([lat2, lng2], {color: 'red', fillColor: '#f03', fillOpacity: 0.1, radius: r2 * 1000}).addTo(m1);
        L.marker([lat1, lng1], {icon: green}).addTo(m1);
        L.circle([lat1, lng1], {color: 'red', fillColor: '#f03', fillOpacity: 0.1, radius: r1 * 1000}).addTo(m1);
        L.marker([r3(mid.lat), r3(mid.lng)], {icon: red}).addTo(m1);
        L.marker([r3(S1_latlng.lat), r3(S1_latlng.lng)]).addTo(m1);
        L.marker([r3(S2_latlng.lat), r3(S2_latlng.lng)]).addTo(m1);
    }
}






function r3(x) {return r(x,3);}
function r(x,exp) {
    var round=Math.pow(10,exp),r=x*round;
    return Math.round(r)/round;
}

function LatLng2Cartesian(lat_deg,lng_deg)
{
    var lat_rad = lat_deg*DEG2RAD,lng_rad = lng_deg*DEG2RAD,cos_lat = Math.cos(lat_rad);
    return {x: Math.cos(lng_rad)*cos_lat, y: Math.sin(lng_rad)*cos_lat, z: Math.sin(lat_rad)};
}

function Cartesian2LatLng(P)
{
    var P_xy = {x: P.x, y:P.y, z:0}
    return {lng: Math.atan2(P.y,P.x)/DEG2RAD, lat: Math.atan2(P.z,vecLen(P_xy))/DEG2RAD};
}

function vecLen(v) {
    return Math.sqrt(v.x * v.x + v.y * v.y + v.z * v.z);
}

function vecScale(scale, v) {
    return {x: scale * v.x, y: scale * v.y, z: scale * v.z};
}


function crossProd(v1, v2) {
    return {
        x: v1.y * v2.z - v1.z * v2.y,
        y: v1.z * v2.x - v1.x * v2.z,
        z: v1.x * v2.y - v1.y * v2.x
    };
}

function distance(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2) {
    return getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2)
}
function getDistanceFromLatLonInKm(lon1, lat1, lon2, lat2) {//haversine
    var dLat = deg2rad(lat2-lat1);  // deg2rad below
    var dLon = deg2rad(lon2-lon1);
    var a = Math.sin(dLat/2) * Math.sin(dLat/2) + Math.cos(deg2rad(lat1)) * Math.cos(deg2rad(lat2)) * Math.sin(dLon/2) * Math.sin(dLon/2);
    var c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));
    var d = R * c; // Distance in km
    //console.error({lat1,lon2,dLat,dLon,a,c,d});
    return d;
}

function deg2rad(deg) {return deg * DEG2RAD;}
</script>
```

Thanks in advance